# Laravel 5.4 Add a difference between views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the same view to show one post and random post

routes

```
Route::get('posts/{id}', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::get('get-random-post', 'PostsController@getRandomPost');
```

methods in **PostsController**

```
public function show($id) {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }


public function getRandomPost() {
        $post = Post::inRandomOrder()
            ->where('is_published', 1)->first();
        return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["id" => $post->id]);
}
```

but now I need to add a small difference between two views. How can I do that?

**UPD**
I added variable `$randomPost` to methods in Controller

```
public function show($id) {
        $randomPost = false;
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'randomPost'));
    }
public function getRandomPost() {
        $randomPost = true;
        $post = Post::inRandomOrder()
            ->where('is_published', 1)->first();
        return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["id" => $post->id]);
    }
```

and added code below to `show` view

```
@if($randomPost)
        some text
@endif
```

but I don't know how to pass variable from `getRandomPost()` to view?

**UPD2**

As result I used session, it works but I'm not sure about it

method

```
public function getRandomPost() {
    $post = Post::inRandomOrder()
        ->where('is_published', 1)->first();
    session()->flash('random_post', 'ok');
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["id" => $post->id]);
}
```

view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <a href="{{ action('HomeController@index') }}">Home page</a>
    <h2>#{{$post->id}}</h2>
    {!! nl2br(e($post->text)) !!}

    <?php if(session()->has('random_post')){
        echo '<div style="text-align: center">';
        echo link_to_action('PostsController@getRandomPost', 'Random Post', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());
        echo '</div>';
    }?>
@stop
```

Comment: You can pass a variable to determine if it is random post or not and with that make difference

Comment: What's the difference between the views? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I updated my question. I use Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session flash, it lasts only on subsequent request:

```
// set
session()->flash('random_post', 'ok');

// check
if(session()->has('random_post')){
    // is random
```

Comment: I don't want to use session

Comment: The other way to add persistence between two requests is a querystring variable: posts/1?random=true

Comment: Oh no, no, no, it's not a way  I'd want to go.

Comment: if that is the case you cannot use redirect, simply render the same view but with an additional var: return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'randomPost'));

Comment: I used your solution with session, UPD2 in my question

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to call the function from the `getRandomPost` by passing a default variable through.

```
public function show($id, $randomPost = false) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'randomPost'));
}

public function getRandomPost() {
    $post = Post::inRandomOrder()->where('is_published', 1)->first();
    $this->show($post->id, true);
}
```